# php-function fsockopen() doesn't work

Tags: php

I just started to study php and I'm reading about `fsockopen()`. I tried to repeat an example from the book, but as result I get an empty page without any information.

```
<?php
function get_content ($hostname, $path)
{
    $line = "";
    $fp = fsockopen($hostname, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    if(!$fp) echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
    else 
    {
        $headers = "GET $path HTTP/1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Host: $hostname\r\n";
        $headers .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
        fwrite($fp, $headers);
        while (!feof($fp))
        {
            $line .= fgets($fp, 1024);
        }
        fclose ($fp);
    }
    return $line;

    $hostname = "www.php.net";
    $path = "/index.php";
    //set_time_limit(180);
    echo get_content ($hostname, $path);
}
?>
```

What's wrong with this code and why it doesn't work?

Comment: It's possible that the modules/dependences required for `fsockopen()` aren't installed. If you enable [PHP error messages](http://www.mjdigital.co.uk/blog/php-display-errors-at-runtime/), it'll probably tell you the fatal error it's having.

Comment: How can I check if modules/dependences required for `fsockopen()` are installed?

Comment: ALWAYS if you see a blank page, check your `apache error log` (on *nix: /var/log/apache2/error.log). Also if you're trying to grab contents of particular site, try doing this with `PHP cURL`: http://pl1.php.net/curl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lines after the `return` statements will never be reached.

You may want to get the last three lines of your function, out of the function.

```
function get_content($hostname, $path) {
    $line = "";
    $fp   = fsockopen($hostname, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    if (!$fp) echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
    else {
        $headers = "GET $path HTTP/1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Host: $hostname\r\n";
        $headers .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
        fwrite($fp, $headers);
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $line .= fgets($fp, 1024);
        }
        fclose($fp);
    }

    return $line;
}

//Outside the function!
$hostname = "www.php.net";
$path     = "/index.php";
//set_time_limit(180);
echo get_content($hostname, $path);
```

Comment: @truslivii.lev: Sure thing, it happens :). The use of a modern IDE can mitigate the effect. (When I copied your code to PhpStorm, it immediately told me that the lines were unreachable).